# Eliminate optional fields from meta model

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, modeling

I've created a meta model to store technical measurements, in order to manage them in Java after I parsed them with JAXB.

I want to support scalars (angle, length, temperature, etc.) and also vectors (like direction).

As a bonus I'd also like to support matrices (maybe for rotations). Below an example model.

```
<measure name="X">
   <properties>
      <property name="description" value="length"/>
      <property name="unit" value="mm"/>
      <property name="tolerance" value="1"/>
   </properties>

   <scalar>150.157</scalar>
   <vector/>
   <matrix/>
</measure>
```

I don't like the current approach where I have three optional entries for the three possible value types.

Are there better, unified approaches without the use of optional fields that are also easily parsable?

Comment: I could add an enum attribute **type** (with: scalar, vector, matrix) to the element **measure** and instead of the optional elements, use one mandatory element **value**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the approaches is to use substitution groups. You declare a global element, say, `value`, of some `ValueType` and reference it where needed.

Then you add further types (like `ScalarType`, `VectorType`, `MatrixType`) which extend `ValueType` and declare global elements `scalar`, `vector`, `matrix` with `substitutionGroup="tns:value"`. This would mean that these elements may subsitute `value`.

In your `MeasureType` you will simply include `<xs:element ref="value"/>` and this will allow `scalar`, `vector`, `matrix` appear instead.

XJC can compile this kind of schemas and JAXB works quite fine with substitution groups. You`ll get a`JAXBElement`-typed property.

Here is an [example of schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/1.1.0/expr.xsd) which uses this approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
   version="1.1.3">
   <!-- 
      filter is an OGC Standard.
      Copyright (c) 2002,2003,2004,2010 Open Geospatial Consortium.
      To obtain additional rights of use, visit http://www.opengeospatial.org/legal/ .

      Updated: 2012-07-21
   -->
   <xsd:element name="Add" type="ogc:BinaryOperatorType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="Sub" type="ogc:BinaryOperatorType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="Mul" type="ogc:BinaryOperatorType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="Div" type="ogc:BinaryOperatorType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="PropertyName" type="ogc:PropertyNameType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="Function" type="ogc:FunctionType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="Literal" type="ogc:LiteralType"
      substitutionGroup="ogc:expression"/>
   <xsd:element name="expression" type="ogc:ExpressionType" abstract="true"/>
   <!-- <xsd:complexType name="ExpressionType" abstract="true" mixed="true"/>
     -->
   <xsd:complexType name="ExpressionType" abstract="true"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="BinaryOperatorType">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ogc:ExpressionType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element ref="ogc:expression" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="FunctionType">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ogc:ExpressionType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element ref="ogc:expression" minOccurs="0"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="LiteralType">
      <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
         <xsd:extension base="ogc:ExpressionType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:any minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="PropertyNameType">
      <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
         <xsd:extension base="ogc:ExpressionType"/>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: *The type of the substitutable elements must be the same as, or derived from, the type of the head element* [taken from here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_subst.asp). What do I gain over using sth. like *<value type="scalar"/>*? A vector has multiple components, a scalar has only one component -- so optimally I'd use multiple xml (sub)elements to represent a vector. Otherwise I have to string encode it (e.g. (1.0,0.0,0.0)).

Comment: But to be fair, my question was about eliminating optional fields and you did answer that!

Comment: What do you gain? I would argue that `<scalar .../>` is syntactically better than `<value type="scalar" .../>`. Also you have type safety as the `scalar` element has a specified `ScalarType` type, not just some generic type.

Comment: You are also free to design your types so that they represent vectors or scalars or matrices optimally. Subelements or whatever.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand right away that you can further add subelements (with xsd:complexContent and xsd:extension). So basically `<value/>` can be substituted (or must, if it is abstract) with `<scalar>1</scalar>` or `<vector><c>1.0</c><c>0.0</c></vector>`.

Comment: @mike Correct. Basically with anything you'll define in the schema in the same substitution group.